# how can I add a row in a locally stored array in Ionic3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to add a row to a locally stored array

Here I leave a photo with what I currently have

[image]

I want to add a row to array "Encuestas" with the following code

```html
public Encuestas :any[];


 this.Encuestas= [
            {
              id:"3",
              mysqlid:"1",
              nombre:"Encuesta de Cigarrillos",
              img:"albums",
              descripcion:"Encuesta Aplicable"
            }
           ]

constructor(public http: Http,public local:Storage) {}


PostEncuestas(){
      this.local.ready().then(()=>{
            this.local.set('encuestas',this.Encuestas);
      })  
    }
```

when I call the function. the array "encuestas" is replaced entirely by the sent array

is there a push method on ionic3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first try to load the array with:

```
this.local.get('encuestas').then((data) => this.Encuestas = data);
```

Apply the updates to the `Encuestas` array and then do the `PostEncuestas()`

To push the data use:

```
this.Encuestas.push({
          id:"3",
          mysqlid:"1",
          nombre:"Encuesta de Cigarrillos",
          img:"albums",
          descripcion:"Encuesta Aplicable"
        });
```

Comment: I had thought of that solution but my only question is. what happens when the array is too long? affects performance?

Comment: Well if you have big array you could start using more approachs, like an in-memory paginator to show only a couple of items from that array and not the whole array, how you show the information will make the UI loss performance. Ionic already has a solution for that, check this: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/virtual-scroll/VirtualScroll/